# logging out the user if new session is created on the same browser using php

Tags: php, session

i have a system with multiple **user levels** , when one user logged in then on the same browser another user loggin, i want to loggout the existing user.
i have no idea how to go..
here is my code:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('../db/db_connection.php');
$user_session=$_SESSION['username'];
$user_s_q=mysql_query("select userlevel from users where  username='$user_session'");
$se_row=mysql_fetch_array($user_s_q);
    $level=$se_row['userlevel'];


if(empty($_SESSION['username'])&& empty($_SESSION['userLevel'])){
    header("location:../index.php");
    }

    elseif($level!='admin'){

        header("location:../index.php");
        }
   elseif($level>1){

       //logout the existing user

      }

    else{
       //display content

          }
```

how can i do this? any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to destroy the old session:

```
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
$_SESSION=array();
```

Or use the example on the php manual for session_destroy (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)